# Two datatables export at two different Excel CSV files

Tags: c#, asp.net

You se finally I have 2 datatables filled with different data, now I have a button that allows me to send one datatable to a .CSV Excel file like this:

```
string name="Dat_Agrup";
HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
context.Response.Clear();

foreach (System.Data.DataColumn column in _myDataTable.Columns)
{
    context.Response.Write("name"+ ",");
}

context.Response.Write(Environment.NewLine);

foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in _myDataTable.Rows)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < _myDataTable.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        context.Response.Write(row[i].ToString().Replace(",", string.Empty) + ",");
    }

    context.Response.Write(Environment.NewLine);
}

context.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + name + ".csv");
context.Response.End();
```

Now this code works perfect it maybe missing some lines like where I declare the datatable but just trust me it works :D, now if I want to save the second datatable using the same code in the same action_button is those not work, i use this next code:

```
string name2="Centroids";
HttpContext context2 = HttpContext.Current;
context2.Response.Clear();

foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in _myDataTable2.Rows)
{   
    for (int i = 0; i < _myDataTable2.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        context2.Response.Write(row[i].ToString().Replace(",", string.Empty) + ",");
    }

    context2.Response.Write(Environment.NewLine);
}

context2.Response.ContentType = "text2/csv";
context2.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + name2 + ".csv");
context2.Response.End();
```

It only save the first datatable and ignores the rest of the code can anyone explain the reason or why this happens, much appreciated any kind of help.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is this line in your first code snippet:

```
context.Response.End();
```

The [`HttpResponse.End()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.end.aspx) "stops execution of the page, and raises the EndRequest event."

If you'd like to continue processing the code, you can't call that method until the end.

Comment: thaks for the answer like always i solve this now have a diferent problem but thank you anyways.

Comment: @JUAN Yeah, I was trying to think of a better approach for your problem, but I'm not sure.  You may just want to save the two CSV files on the web server, then provide links to those files to your end user (rather than returning the file in your response).